# Sorting names for an on-call schedule using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to programing in VBA (or programing at all) so excuse me in advance if my question is a little dumb.

I have the problem of trying to create a code that can automatically fill in a schedule at work. The schedule is supposed to be able to take any number of employees and assign their names on a repeating schedule based on monday to friday within all 52 weeks of the year (The schedule excludes holidays, the employers themselves will have to fill in the days when buisness is closed).

What I am trying to do is to ensure that nobody is scheduled two days in a row and that everyone has a rough equal amount of days scheduled. My solution for this is to shuffle the names accordingly:

12345, 23451, 34512, 45123, 51234.

If five people needs to be scheduled it would go from this:
[image: Unshuffled]

To this:

[image: Shuffled]

I've been trying this for a while now but can't make it work. The problem is that I don't know how to make the schedule like this with x number of names. if the number was constant it would be easy but I need the schedule to be created automatically based on x names.

One thought I had was to create some sort of loop that enters data throughout the schedule by first entering the names x times (where x = total number of names put into the list of persons to be scheduled), and then skipping the x + 1:th name each time.

With five people it would look like this (with the skipped number within () ):
12345(1)23451(2)34512(3)45123(4)51234(5) (repeat utnil whole year has been filled in).

The reason I have to do this is because some of our departments have 5 persons in them, and I want to make sure they're not scheduled for the same task on the same day each week.

I would be really thankful if someone has a solution or some helpful input to this problem.

Cheers!

Comment: You could push the numbers into an array then bring them out in different order, but what happens if someone leaves or joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithm which will produce the desired results:

```
Sub createDutyRoster(numOfEmployees As Integer, numOfWeeks As Integer)

    Dim dutyRosterWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim emplCount As Integer, i As Integer, n As Integer, tempEmplCount As Integer

    Set dutyRosterWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duty Roster")

    With dutyRosterWS

        ' insert headers
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Week/day"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Monday"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Tuesday"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "Wednesday"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "Thursday"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Friday"

        For i = 1 To numOfWeeks

            ' weeks
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = i

            ' employee count
            If emplCount < numOfEmployees Then
                emplCount = emplCount + 1
            ElseIf emplCount = numOfEmployees Then
                emplCount = 1
            End If
            tempEmplCount = emplCount

            ' insert for monday to friday
            For n = 2 To 6
                .Cells(i + 1, n) = tempEmplCount
                If tempEmplCount < numOfEmployees Then
                    tempEmplCount = tempEmplCount + 1
                ElseIf tempEmplCount = numOfEmployees Then
                    tempEmplCount = 1
                End If
            Next n

        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

**How it works**

1. Add a new worksheet called "Duty Roster" (or rename it in the code)
2. Call the subroutine with the following parameters: a) the number of employees, b) the number of iso weeks in the given year (some years have 53 iso weeks not just 52). E.g. `Call createDutyRoster(15, 52)`

**Example with 15 employees**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! It works like a charm, and I really learned something in the process! =)

Many many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, you could make the code a little less verbose by writing a small counter function which returns the `emplCount` and `tempEmplCount` values based on the same rules (conditionals) as the original code, but I'll leave that up to you ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it but I thought the code you suggested gave me a good overview of what was going on, so I think I'll go with that so I can easily go back and look at it again if I encounter some similar problem :)